# Excel JS Add-In Shared Runtime Work with IE11?

Tags: excel, office-js

It looks like the shared runtime example on the page below is focused on situations where the Add-In browser is using edge (as opposed to IE11). I am not able to update the window.sharedState data and see the updates in my Task Pane. I can see the updates if I troubleshoot the add-in by hitting localhost with my Chrome browser. Any thoughts on how to make this work? I believe my browser is IE11 because my windows version is 1809.

[screenshot of my add-in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uza93.png)

Comment: what is the "page below"?

Comment: Do you have a `<Runtimes>` element in the manifest? This article says that if you do, then IE is always used: [Browsers used by Office add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins).

Comment: It is using the element. That is the what the documentation is saying is required to make the shared runtime work. And it says that’s required. So I guess that answers my question? The shared runtime is only available for excel on windows and only uses the IE11 browser. Shared runtime does not work with the newer edge browser if you have the latest windows OS/office 365 versions. Is that correct?

Comment: So for some reason my configuration is not working for the shared runtime.

Comment: Your question refers to an "example on the page below". What page? What example?

Comment: I see what your asking. There is a image link at the bottom of my post that shows my add-in project. I’m trying to show my source code so people can see what my issue is. Here is the link again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uza93.png

Comment: I see. A terminological confusion. I don't think of a screenshot of code as a page. In the function `updateSharedState`, does the call of `devserverLog` log the new value or the old value?

Comment: It’s logging the new value. And when I update sharedState from my taskpane that is updating as well. So the issue is that the two sides are not sharing the others updated state. Except my taskpane is getting the initial state that is defined at the top of my functions.js file.

Comment: Something is not clear to me in your description. `updateSharedState` runs in the task pane; so if it is logging the new value (changed in the custom function), then it _is_ getting a `window.sharedstate.test` that was updated in the custom function. What am I missing?